# Deserialize a BST in C

Tags: c, deserialization, binary-search-tree

I am trying to construct a BST given a string. It is assumed that my strlen will always be in the power of 2 so that I can have a structure with the ends always leveled, like so:

[image: Tree]

I am having trouble starting this function. I've written a helper that willd construct a tree up to the final points here:

```
tree* build(int height)
{
    int i;
    tree *t = malloc(sizeof(tree));
    t.tag = NODE;
    t.u = node;
    t.u.node->left = build(height - 1);
    t.u.node->right = build(height - 1);
    if(height == 1)
    {
        return t;
    }
}
```

I would like to reach the end of each node and append the first two chars and so forth throughout the rest of the tree. I am lost, though.

Here are the structs:

```
typedef struct tagged_tree tree;

struct node {
    tree *left, *right;
};

union tree_union {
    struct node node;
    char leaf;
};

enum tree_tag {
    NODE, LEAF
};

struct tagged_tree {
    enum tree_tag tag;
    union tree_union u;
};
```

Comment: You can do what you *seem* to be asking with a pair of `tagged_tree` queues, swapped after each level is built, until you reach a single node, which will be the root of your queue.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.  It is unclear how you get the string information into the tree.  Your build function does not always return a value.  Your compiler should be warning about that.  If it doesn't, find a way to turn on more compiler warnings — or get a better compiler.  I think the test around the return is unwanted; you simply need to return `t` every time the function is called.